# creating an array to use in autofiltering VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I would really appreciate any help with the following:

I am getting user input from "myData" range by way of colored text to use in autofiltering a bigger range - so here is the code for finding the address of the red texted cells and their values:

```
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("myData")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    If rCell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then 
    Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
    Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Next rCell
```

I have to put these findings into an array and use them to filter the selection (the selection is made and selected at this point which is "myTable"); of course the findings do tell us which fields and which values to be used: so if the findings say were: c18 "x", d19 "y" and d21 "z" the autofilter would have to say:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("myTable")
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="x"
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="y", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="z"
        End With
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
        Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 3
End With
```

Both codes work as they are but of course I have to write code to automate the whole process. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better and faster way but I was able to solve it with following code:

I read the criteria into an array by way of the following code:

```
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("myData")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

    If rCell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then '3 = Red

        Counter = Counter + 1

        myAddress(Counter) = rCell.Column - 1
        myValues(Counter) = rCell.Value

        Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
        Debug.Print myAddress(Counter), myValues(Counter)

    End If

Next rCell

ReDim Preserve myAddress(Counter + 1)
ReDim Preserve myValues(Counter + 1)
```

Then I was able to use the the array in the autofiltering as such:

```
Range("myFirst").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set myTable = Selection

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("myTable")
            .AutoFilter

            For i = 1 To Counter
                .AutoFilter Field:=myAddress(i), Criteria1:=myValues, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            Next i
```

'
            End With
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
            Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    End With